# MYSQLI How to display and count date for the last 3 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display and count date for the last 3 days but sadly I'm getting this result This is my code

```
    
    SELECT date_opened, COUNT(DISTINCT(date_opened))
    FROM daily_report
    WHERE date_opened>=DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY )
```

**RESULT**

| DATE_OPENED | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-05 11:27:31 | 6 |

**THIS IS MY TABLE**

| DATE_OPENED |
| --- |
| 2021-03-03 08:46:33 |
| 2021-03-03 00:00:00 |
| 2021-03-04 00:00:05 |
| 2021-03-05 00:04:02 |
| 2021-03-05 00:03:45 |
| 2021-03-05 11:27:31 |
| 2021-03-05 11:27:31 |

**This is the result I want**

| DATE_OPENED | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-03 | 2 |
| 2021-03-04 | 1 |
| 2021-03-05 | 4 |

Please help I'm having a hard time on this one

Comment: An aggregation (`COUNT()`) without `GROUP BY` doesn't really make sense especially when you want to show it by specific column; in your case `date_opened`. Therefore, your query required a `GROUP BY`.. can you guess which column to `GROUP BY`?

Comment: What's your mysql version

Comment: group by date opened?  My Mysql version is XAMP Control PANEL V3.2.4

Comment: Correct.. and since you're extracting `date` out of a timestamp value, you can make use of `DATE(date_opened)`. Also, run `SELECT @@version` to get MySQL version.

Comment: This is mY VERSION 10.4.14-MariaDB

Comment: So it work but I only a total of 6 in the second column. Why i am getting 6 total, my number of data in this table is 7

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GzOLUbF11kCdFR6mBYom2zdijZHPFUfK/view?usp=sharing  So it work but the total of Count is 6, why am I getting 6 total, my number of data is 7

Comment: See the "window function" `LAG()` for "last 3 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```
SELECT DATE(date_opened), COUNT(DATE(date_opened))
    FROM daily_report
    WHERE DATE(date_opened)>=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY )
GROUP BY DATE(date_opened)
```

Use `DATE()` to extract date from a timestamp value and I don't think you need `DISTINCT`.

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=1dfc1203abb1e3d67fd476e512c4d16c).

Comment: But note that functions cannot use indexes

Answer (score 2):

If your MySQL version support CTE you can try to use CTE recursion to make a calendar then do `outer join`.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte 
AS (
  SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY ) fromDt,CURDATE() toDt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE_ADD(fromDt,INTERVAL 1 DAY) , toDt
  FROM cte 
  WHERE fromDt < toDt
)
SELECT t1.fromDt ,COUNT(t2.date_opened)
FROM cte t1 
LEFT JOIN daily_report t2 ON t1.fromDt = DATE(t2.date_opened) 
GROUP BY t1.fromDt
```

**Note**: The `OUTER JOIN` makes sure your source table didn't store any date of data it can still display count as zero.

[sample fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WEtxR8TMDAeV6Hij9kmpB/0)